# How do I call the FA2 balance_of endpoint through Truffle?

Tags: michelson, javascript, testing, truffle, fa2

I have written a contract to implement FA2 and I have a Truffle/JavaScript setup to test this contract while running against a sandboxed node. I can test the `transfer` endpoint and the `update_operators` endpoint, but I don't know how to construct the right JavaScript object to test the `balance_of` or the `token_metadata_registry` endpoint.

The input value as defined in LIGO (Pascal dialect) to `token_metadata_registry` is:

```
type token_metadata_registry_parameter is contract(address);
```

The input type to the `balance_of` endpoint is `balance_of_parameter_michelson` defined as

```
type balance_of_request is record
    owner: token_owner;
    token_id: token_id;
end;

type balance_of_response is record
    request: balance_of_request;
    balance: token_balance;
end;

type balance_of_callback is contract(list(balance_of_response));

type balance_of_parameter is record
    requests: list(balance_of_request);
    callback: balance_of_callback;
end;

type balance_of_request_michelson is michelson_pair_right_comb(balance_of_request);

type balance_of_response_auxiliary is record [
    balance: token_balance;
    request: balance_of_request_michelson;
]

type balance_of_response_michelson is michelson_pair_right_comb(balance_of_response_auxiliary);

type balance_of_callback_michelson is contract(list(balance_of_response_michelson));

type balance_of_parameter_auxiliary is record [
    requests: list(balance_of_request_michelson);
    callback: balance_of_callback_michelson;
]

type balance_of_parameter_michelson is michelson_pair_right_comb(balance_of_parameter_auxiliary);
```

Comment: Maybe I need to create another contract which can act like a wrapper for this function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot check if the entrypoint returns the balance with JavaScript, because the entrypoint doesn't return a value but emits a transaction. I didn't try it for a FA2 token contract but to test a FA1.2 token contract with Truffle, I wrote a simple contract that would call the FA1.2 balance_of entrypoint and receive the balance on a different entrypoint before saving it in its storage. I would then fetch the storage of this contract to verify that the balance is what was expected.

Comment: That sounds like a fine approach. Could you include the relevant code of the wrapper contract, the contract that calls the balance_of endpoint?

Comment: This contract: https://github.com/claudebarde/tzip7-implementation/blob/master/contracts/TestContract.religo, it tests all the view entrypoints of a FA1.2 token contract.